# Why there's no DD image for Windows 10 UEFI+GPT+NTFS

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, gpt, liveusb

I'm currently installing an Windows 10 and realized that, it's so difficult to create a windows 10 bootable installaion media.

Since installaion.wim is larger than 4 GiB, FAT32 is not working. I tried windows2usb and rufus, and got so many problems about the NTFS driver.

It would be really helpful if someone creates a working DD image for windows 10 installaion media. Are there any reason that nobody did it?

Comment: Because every Windows tool to create a Windows boot disk is simple and works without problem. Are you doing that from Linux, because there shouldn't be any issues with the NTFS driver on Windows? I'm confused, since rufus runs on Windows.

Comment: MS Provides a [tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) for doing this, I've never had any problems with it. It will even make an image file of the install media for you.

Comment: @phuclv No. I tried to do that from Linux, but ends up using windows rufus. None of them works, and I also tried Microsoft media creation tool, but unable to download it at all.

Comment: *How* to create bootable install media is on topic here. "Why has nobody (*people*) done it" is a question about people and not computers. As a result it would be off topic here. That question is also based on a several faulty premises: that `dd` is the best way, that there are no tools already for essentially the same task. If you are having a problem with a specific tool then you should be asking how to make that tool work, not why people haven't kludged a widget onto it for one specific rare task. Otherwise you should look for the right tool for the job.

Comment: @CliffArmstrong This link only shows "Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)", the mediaCreationTool has already disappeared.

Comment: @Mokubai Sorry but I was just VERY angry about what microsoft does. I finally found a working solution: Firstly install a complete Windows 7, then launch Windows 10 installation tool from the working windows 7.

Comment: @recolic if that page is showing only the ISO then the webpage is detecting a non-Windows OS. To download the media creator you will need to use an extension in your browser to switch the user agent to appear as a Windows machine.

Comment: @recolic As Mokubai says, the page looks at your user agent and tries to direct you the best tools given your system. Since the Media Creation Tool is a windows executable... it will link you to an ISO file instead. Last I checked, GNU Linux & Mac have plentiful cd/dvd writing software options to choose from for writing that ISO to a disk.

Comment: Yeah. MediaCreationTool by Microsoft is a good idea, if it's not failing with "Unknown reason" just now.

Comment: even on Linux there are lots of ways to write the Windows ISO to USB if you've looked around google https://itsfoss.com/bootable-windows-usb-linux/ https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/create-a-bootable-windows-10-usb-in-linux/ https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/06/create-bootable-windows-10-usb-ubuntu